# Unserializing and serializing models for models between backend and frontend (Angular 6)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Is there a better way of being able to do this? I want to create a method for every model that I have to serialize it for transport to the backend.

Certain properties will come from the backend into the application in the form of an ID which the frontend will lookup in an object store.

I wanted to have the SerializedAnswer interface be able to have user and question of type number, but I had to create a new parent interface of Answer in order to do that which allows for the multiple types.

What I originally wanted to do was:

```
interface SerializedAnswer extends Answer {
  inventory: number;
  question: number;
  user: number;
}
```

This gives the following error:

```
[ts]
Interface 'SerializedAnswer' incorrectly extends interface 'Answer'.
Types of property 'inventory' are incompatible.
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Inventory'.
```

This works but it seems a bit cumbersome and repetitive:

```
import { User } from './user';
import { Question } from './question';

interface AnswerInterface {
  id: number;
  user: User | number;
  question: Question | number;
  response: number;
}

interface SerializedAnswer extends AnswerInterface {
  id: number;
  user: number;
  question: number;
  response: number;
}

class Answer {
  id: number;
  user: User;
  question: Question;
  response: number;

  serialize(): SerializedAnswer {
    return Object.assign(this, {
      user: this.user.id,
      question: this.question.id
    });
  }
}
```

I would like to be able to do something like this in a service:

```
function getAnswer(id: number): Observable<Answer> {
  this._apiService.get<SerializedAnswer>(['answer', id]).pipe(map(res => {
    return new Answer({
      ...res,
      ... { user: this._userService.find(res.user) },
      ... { question: this._questionService.find(res.question) }
    });
  }));
}

function saveAnswer(answer: Answer): Observable<Answer> {
  return this._apiService.post(['answer', 'save'], answer.serialize());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that this is possible in Typescript with Declaration Merging.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html

You can have an interface with the same name of a class, which allows you to create a class that automatically implements all of the properties of the interface that it implements.

```
interface AnswerInterface {
  id: number;
  createdAt?: number;
  updatedAt?: number;
  inventory: Inventory | number;
  question: Question | number;
  user: number;
  response: number; // 1 = Strongly Disagree, 4 = Strongly Agree
}

export interface SerializedAnswer extends AnswerInterface { }
export class SerializedAnswer implements AnswerInterface {
  inventory: number;
  question: number;
}

export interface Answer extends AnswerInterface { }
export class Answer implements AnswerInterface {
    inventory: Inventory;
    question: Question;

    public constructor(init?: Partial<Answer>) {
        Object.assign(this, init);
    }

    serialize(): SerializedAnswer {
      return Object.assign(this, {
        question: this.question.id,
        inventory: this.inventory.id
      });
    }
}
```